# Getting NullPointerException with JLabel array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, nullpointerexception, jlabel

I have searched for an answer and found none. I have declared a JLabel array inside a class to be able to edit its text from another class:

```
public static JLabel[] portion = new JLabel[11];
```

And I set its initial text just before adding these labels to a panel:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++){
        portion[i].setText("0.00%");
    }
```

When I try to compile my code to test what I have so far, I get a `NullPointerException`, and Eclipse points to my line of code:

```
portion[i].setText("0.00%");
```

Any advise is appreciated.

Comment: You have created an array, you now need to populate the array; current it is an array with 11 nulls

Comment: How would I populate it? As I am trying to populated it to all be "0.00%" initially.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 4):

You have created an array, you now need to populate the array; current it is an array with 11 nulls

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    portion[i] = new JLabel();
    portion[i].setText("0.00%");
}
```

or simply

```
for(int i = 0; i < 11; i++) {
    portion[i] = new JLabel("0.00%");
}
```

Comment: Tried your first suggestion, and it works. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
public static JLabel[] portion = new JLabel[11];
```

is just like creating array of nulls, meaning array portion array is empty.

You should now iterate it through and populate the array with actual JLable objects.

And then try assigning values through setText method.